# SonarQube + redmine plugin - connect button not working

Tags: redmine, sonarqube

I've installed SonarQube 4.3 + redmine plugin, 
but, in redmine plugin configuration page "connect" button is not working, 
and I can't check connection to redmine from Sonar.

Can you tell me what could be wrong?